# Elasticsearch multiple indices per beats?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, metricbeat

I am using filebeat and I want to also introduce metricbeat. Filebeat output is indexed in logstash-* however I need a different index with only the data from metricbeat (such as metricbeat-test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd} ) These will run together on a single server.

How can I instruct logstash to index the filebeat stuff in logstash-* and IF it is metricbeat to go on and use another index?

More or less I need an IF statement however I am not sure what I should include there!

My logstash config looks like:

> output {   elasticsearch {
>       hosts => "10.0.0.5:9200"
>       manage_template => "true"
>       index => "logstash-test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
>       document_type => "apache"
>       } }

Answer (score 2):

When any Beat sends data to Logstash it will add the destination index to the `[@metadata][beat]` field. By default the Beat will set this value to its own name (e.g. filebeat). And if you want to customize the value you can set the `output.logstash.index` configuration option.

To take advantage of the metadata that is present in all events coming from Beats you must configure the elasticsearch output in Logstash as follows:

```
output {
  if [@metadata][beat] {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost:9200"
      manage_template => false
      index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    }   
  }   
}
```

This is from the [Beats documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/5.1/logstash-installation.html#logstash-setup) on how to use them with Logstash. I added the conditional so that this output is used only for your Beats data. You would configure another elasticsearch output for the other data coming through the pipeline.

Lastly, because you are using the `filebeat-*` and `metricbeat-*` indices **you must** manually install the provided index templates. There is index template provided in the download package for each Beat. There is a template for Elasticsearch 2.x and 5.x, use the appropriate one.

You install the template with curl ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-template.html#load-template-manually)). For example,

`curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/filebeat' -d@/etc/filebeat/filebeat.template.json`

Comment: I did what you suggested but it doesnt work. Everything works fine until the last step which is from logstash --> elasticsearch. Nothing is getting indexed and I am not sure why by doing what you suggested logstash doesnt talk to elasticsearch at all. My topology is filebeat-->logstash-->redis-->logstash-->es.. all the steps until the last logstash are fine and working but elasticsearch doesnt receive anything

Comment: You didn't mention Redis in your original question. With Redis this loop it's likely that that the `@metadata` is not included when going from Logstash -> Redis so the `[@metadata][beat]` may be missing. I recommend using `output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }` in the final Logstash to debug what's coming in from Redis.

Comment: The problem is on the key value on the redis input of logstash. I dont know why this it doesnt work since my output config looks like this 'redis {
    host => "172.21.0.2"
    port => "6379"
    key => "%{[@metadata][beat]}"
    data_type => "list"' which is fine, however when I set ' key => "%{[@metadata][beat]}"' as in redis input it doesnt work... I have no clue what is going on here lol